# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class de.ehsun.coloredtimebar.TimelineView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, kotlin, datetimepicker

I'm working on a app in which user can reserve a seat. User has to choose a time range for his booking. I wanted a time range picker in which I can customize the time whereas user can only choose time from 07:00 to 19:00. I found a library called colored-time-selector https://github.com/ehsunshine/colored-time-selector this library has everything what I was looking for.

But I'm facing below error on android kitkat 4.4 it works fine on lollipop and above.

**XML**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background=""
tools:context=".booking.test">

<de.ehsun.coloredtimebar.TimelinePickerView
    android:id="@+id/timelineView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barColorAvailable="@color/available_time_default_color"
    app:barColorHighlight="@color/selector_default_color"
    app:barColorNotAvailable="@color/timeline_default_color"
    app:barWidth="16dp"
    app:fractionLineColor="@color/separatorDark"
    app:fractionLineLength="8dp"
    app:fractionLineWidth="1dp"
    app:fractionPrimaryTextColor="@color/fraction_default_color"
    app:fractionSecondaryTextColor="@color/fraction_default_color"
    app:fractionTextInterval="2"
    app:fractionTextSize="8sp"
    app:timeRange="07:00-19:00" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java**

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

TimelinePickerView tl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test); //shows error over here


    //diamond operator
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("11:00 - 19:15");
    list.add("20:00 - 21:00");

    tl = (TimelinePickerView) findViewById(R.id.timelineView);

    tl.setAvailableTimeRange(list);
    //tl.setPickerDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_camera));

    }
}
```

**Error**

```
    04-16 07:36:18.341 31897-31897/net.cfgvd.bookingE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: net.cfgvd.booking, PID: 31897
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.cfgvd.booking/net.cfgvd.booking.test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class de.ehsun.coloredtimebar.TimelinePickerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class de.ehsun.coloredtimebar.TimelinePickerView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at net.aafushh.smoky.booking.test.onCreate(test.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at net.aafushh.smoky.booking.test.onCreate(test.java:20) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.<init>
    at de.ehsun.coloredtimebar.TimelineView.<init>(TimelineView.kt:15)
    at de.ehsun.coloredtimebar.TimelinePickerView.<init>(TimelinePickerView.kt:15)
    at de.ehsun.coloredtimebar.TimelinePickerView.<init>(TimelinePickerView.kt:14)
    at de.ehsun.coloredtimebar.TimelinePickerView.<init>(TimelinePickerView.kt)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at net.aafushh.smoky.booking.test.onCreate(test.java:20) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Someone please help me on this issue. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The minimum sdkversion of de.ehsun.coloredtimebar.TimelinePickerView is 19. so it works fine in kitkat and above versions. It will not work in below versions than kitkat.